# Feiertage und Urlaubstage

Tags: meaning, difference

Könnte mir jemand folgende Wörter erklären?

Ich habe im Wörterbuch gesucht aber noch nicht verstanden

Sind diese Wörter Synomyne ?

> Feiertage und Urlaubstage

Comment: Guten Abend. Was hast Du denn im Wörterbuch gefunden, was Du nicht verstanden hast? (Tipp: Ein zweisprachiges Wörterbuch wird in diesem Fall möglicherweise deutlich schlechtere Ergebnisse liefern, als ein einsprachiges)

Comment: Vielen Dank .eigentlich ich habe keine ahnung was bedeutet urlaubstage und was ist der unterschied zwischen diese wörter

Comment: Du meinst Du hast überhaupt nicht nachgeschaut?

Comment: They are no more synonyms than _public holidays_ and _paid leave_ are. Which is what each would translate to.

Comment: [Relevant](http://img.funzentrale.com/original/2015/33/2961133499992642224821821-946374.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Feiertage sind Tage, die aus christlichen oder kulturellen Gründen wie Sonntage behandelt werden. Zu diesen Tagen zählen beispielsweise Weihnachten, Ostermontag oder der Tag der deutschen Einheit.

Je nachdem, wo man wohnt und arbeitet, darf an diesen Tagen nicht gearbeitet werden. Ausnahmen sind natürlich Polizei, Krankenhaus, Feuerwehr aber auch Baustellen mit Sondergenehmigung (nicht vollständige Liste). Wenn man an einem Feiertag arbeiten muss, bekommt man meist eine Kompensation, bspw. einen weiteren Urlaubstag oder einen prozentuellen Aufschlag auf das Gehalt. Ansonsten werden Feiertage wie Sonntage gehandhabt, also sind Läden geschlossen usw.

Urlaubstage sind Tage, die man sich freinehmen kann. Nach deutschem Gesetz stehen jeden Arbeitnehmer eine gewisse Anzahl an bezahlten Urlaubstagen mindestens zu. Urlaubstage werden beim Arbeitgeber beantragt, woraufhin dieser beschließt, ob der Urlaub gewährt wird.

Ein wichtiger Unterschied ist, dass Feiertage meist gesetzlich sind und Arbeitgeber sich an diese halten müssen. Urlaubstage können jedoch mit einer Begründung abgelehnt werden, bspw. dass die Firma nicht mehr funktionsfähig wäre,

Comment: Urlaubstage sind bundeseinheitlich geregelt im [BUrlG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/burlg/gesamt.pdf), Feiertage sind geregelt in den einzelnen Landesgesetzen, z.B. [Feiertagsgesetz NRW](https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_bes_text?anw_nr=2&gld_nr=1&ugl_nr=113&bes_id=3367).